# How do i backup a SQL database using PHP?

Tags: php, sql, backup

How do i backup a SQL database using PHP.

Is there a vendor agnostic way to do this that conforms to ANSI SQL?

If not maybe you can list how to do it for each of the database vendors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every database system comes with some program for dumping its contents.

- PostgreSQL: [`pg_dump`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/backup.html)
- MySQL: [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html)
- ...

You can simply call that program from PHP using [`system()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php)
or [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php).

For example, if you use PostgreSQL with enabled [Ident authentication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/auth-methods.html#AUTH-IDENT) and want to dump the Database `test` directly as SQL text to the browser, it's as simple as:

`<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain');
system('pg_dump test');
?>`

When using MySQL with database user and password stored into [`~/.my.cnf`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/option-files.html), it is also very simple:

`<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain');
system('mysqldump test');
?>`

However, **don't do this:**

`<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain');
system('mysqldump -utestuser -ptestpassword test');
?>`

because transmitting a password as command line argument is [very insecure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/password-security.html).

Comment: Am I right in thinking you could also execute this via an SQL query? Some shared hosting providers don't allow system calls.

Comment: If you have a hosting provider who doesn't allow system() or shell_exec(), you should switch to a serious one. Such a restriction doesn't really add security. It's just annoying the customers.

Answer (score 1):

I love [phpmybackuppro](http://www.phpmybackuppro.net/)

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty complicated process. I recommend you use phpmyadmin or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst backing up a database "conformant to ANSI SQL" is possible and admirable, you will still encounter portability issues. The most obvious is that whilst MySQL's dump/restore format is fairly fast, it achieves this principally by using a non-standard extension to SQL. So you can't just hand the dump to PostGresql: it won't work. In fact, PostGresql is also quite slow at handling a huge amount of INSERT statements. It's native dump format uses it's own custom SQL statement optimized for inserting a large amount of data at once.